# Can you modify a foreign key on insert with a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, triggers

I have an issue where a query is inserting into table A, which references table B, but it's using the wrong foreign key for table B.  Is it possible to create a trigger in oracle where if the input foreign key is 'ASDF', we modify it to 'FDSA' before the insert so that we can fix this issue?

Comment: Why not just add the ASDF row to the referenced table?  Then you don't need a trigger at all.

Comment: cannot do that due to many other issues.  Is this possible with a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

In either MySQL or Oracle, you can do this using a `before insert` trigger.

I don't recommend using a trigger for this purpose.  Fixing the input data or adding the new value to the reference table seem to me to be more sensible approaches.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this is done?  I have tried searching for this but can't find any samples.

Comment: @TritonMan . . . Oracle has plenty of examples of writing triggers (say, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/trigger-syntax.html).  I'm sure MySQL does as well.  The logic isn't very hard . . . if the old value then set to the new value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - did you mean "I *don't* recommend using a trigger for this purpose"?

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . Yes, you understood my intention if not what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @GordonLinoff's post - I agree with (what appears to be) his point that a trigger is inappropriate here. However, recognizing that sometimes you have to work with what you're given, if you *were* to use a trigger you'd use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, as in:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TABLE_A_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.FK_FIELD = 'ASDF' THEN 
    :NEW.FK_FIELD = 'FDSA';
  END IF;
END YOUR_TABLE_BI;
```

Best of luck.